# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was doing an assignment for my C class in school and I hit a little snag.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char stringToUpper(char * sName )
{
    while(*sName != '\0')
    {
        stringToUpper (* sName);
        ++* sName;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    char * sName;
    printf("Please enter your name ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Hello %s ", str);
    sName = str;
    stringToUpper(sName);
    printf("Name in uppercase: %s ", sName);
}
```

I tried looking for other solutions already, however I found that everyone else's problems were much more advanced than the level I'm at and really just couldn't follow it. I've still a little new at working with pointers and still a little confused about how they work (only a few weeks into the class) so I feel like the issue has something to do with that. I'm almost certain that the issue has something to do with the while statement.

This is the error I get:

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
>
> sName was 0x41.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Thanks in advanced for whatever help I receive.

Comment: It looks like you are overflowing the 50 bytes buffer (what are you entering?). Also `++*sName;` is incrementing the byte pointed by `sName`, not the pointer as you are expecting..

Comment: What `stringToUpper` is supposed to do?

Comment: `++* sName;` maybe you meant `++sName;`

Comment: Woah.. it looks like a strange recursion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Just my name. and the program goes through the "Please enter your name" and "Hello %s " sections just fine. The program crashes after that. I'm pretty sure it crashed while trying to do the While statement.

Comment: no, no, no. The whole `stingToUpper` looks like a complete mess. You need to learn a bit about pointers. I don't even know where to start correcting it..

Comment: @SouravGhosh The stringToUpper is supposed to make the name inputted uppercase. The reason it's in it's own function is because my prof. wanted it done that way.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm pretty sure the majority of my class is pretty confused about pointers still. Jeez, is it really that bad?

Comment: Oh, if the intention was to actually use the `toupper` function as @dbush is pointing below, it clears it a bit.

Comment: `stringToUpper (* sName);` <- `*sName` is a character, but `stringToUpper` is expecting a pointer and tries to use it as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `stringToUpper` function has some issues:

```
while(*sName != '\0')
{
    stringToUpper (* sName);
    ++* sName;
}
```

- You could be calling `toupper` to change to upper case and assigning the value back to `*sName` instead of having the function call itself.  In fact, the call you had is incorrect because you're passing a `char` to a function expecting a `char *`.  In the next iteration of `stringToUpper`, it attempts to dereference that invalid pointer which causes the crash.
- You should be incrementing `sName` (which points to the current character), not `*sName`.

---

The corrected version:

```
while(*sName != '\0')
{
    *sName=toupper(*sName);
    ++sName;
}
```